# How can I use this helper class to detect the Windows Phone device/emulator resolution?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xna, monogame

Article: http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/optimising-for-large-screen-phones/resolution-specific-considerations.html

I want to use the ResolutionHelper class that is described in the article to detect the resolution of a Windows Phone device/emulator, but I always get the following error message in this line:

```
_size = (Size)DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("PhysicalScreenResolution");
```

The name 'DeviceExtendedProperties' does not exist in the current context

In addition, I don't know how to use the class. I tried to call it like this, but I get an error message:

```
Resolutions currentRes = ResolutionHelper.CurrentResolution();
```

Non-invocable member 'GameName1.ResolutionHelper.CurrentResolution' cannot be used like a method.

What is wrong? How can I use the class?

**UPDATE:** 
I get a new error message in this line:

```
return App.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor == 100;
```

An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Invalid cross-thread access.

What is wrong?

Comment: Drop the brackets on `ResolutionHelper.CurrentResolution`. It's a property, not a method.

Comment: That fixed this error message. But now I get new error message: An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Invalid cross-thread access.